# How to change Mission Control window highlighting

Tags: macos, mission-control

Is there a way to change how the selected window in Mission Control is highlighted in Yosemite? Between my aging eyes and background image, it's just a little too subtle for me to easily notice.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an explicit Mission Control picker for the highlight, nor a slider to increase the highlight size.

However, if you go **System Preferences** >> **Accessibility** >> **Display**, then you will find a number of adjustments that can help you to distinguish the display elements.

The **Increase contrast** is a good one because it makes everything a little "sharper."

You can further increase the **Display contrast**, though a little goes a long way.

Increasing the **Cursor size** might also help, since you'll have an easier time spotting which window is beneath the cursor.

If this still doesn't help, then I'd recommend [submitting a feature request](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) to Apple.